# Consider a function $f \colon U \to X$, if $f$ is the identity when acting on $X$, then $df_x$ is also the identity for all $x \in X$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

While doing an independent project, I ran into this question. Let $X$ be a $k$-dimensional compact manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set such that $X \subset U$. As in the title, consider a smooth function $f \colon U \to X$ such that $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$. Then, is it true that $df_x$ is the identity matrix?

My first guess is that it is not always true. For this, recall what a lefschetz map is. The latter is a function such that on its fixed points $x$ (i.e. $x \in U$ such that $f(x) = x$) $df_x$ does not have $+1$ as an eiganvalue, in other words we do not have $df_x(v) = v$ for all $v$ in $T_x(X)$. So, if the above were true then we would not have lefschetz maps. Is this reasoning correct? Or this depends on the nature of $f$ or $X$?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's something wrong with your setup. If $f\colon U\rightarrow X$ and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in U$, we necessarily have $U\subset X$, from which $X=U$ follows, but the only open, compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the empty set (though, of course, in that case the conclusion holds vacuously).
Also, nothing about this would contradict existence of Lefschetz maps as it makes a significant difference whether you have a single fixed point or a map that is locally the identity.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$. Does this clarification change things?

Comment: But, what if $X$ is a finite set of points. Then could we say that $df_x$ is the identity for all $x \in X$. (With all the assumptions already made about $f$

Comment: That makes sense. Though I'm not sure why you are considering this $U$ and $f$. It seems that all you're asking about is the differential of the identity map on $X$. This should be straightforward to compute, but the computation changes depending on how your definitions go.
This has nothing to do with whether $X$ is a finite or even whether $X$ is compact. The differential of the identity map on any manifold at any point is always the identity map on the corresponding tangent space.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have missed a little bit of context. So, $U$ in this case is the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $X$ and $f$ is just a map such that $f(u)$, for any $u \in U$, is the (unique) closest point at $X$ to $u$. So, I was trying to see if by any chance $f$ could have lefschetz fixed points. The problem I was having was when $f$ was restricted to $X$, which is the identity. So, as long as I know the identity map is not lefschetz. That is why I was asking why $df_x$ would be the identity when restricted to $X$.

Comment: It will be. I'd suggest you try computing that yourself. If you get stuck, feel free to ask for clarification, but then tell us what your definition of the differential is as the computation will be different depending on the definition.

Comment: If you consider $f$ as a map from $U$ to $X$, then the matrix representation of $df_x$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix so asking $df_x$ to be identitiy is meaningless.

Comment: So, taking the argument of Eumenes. If we consider $f \colon U \to X$, then wouldn't $df_x$ for $x \in U$ be a $k \times n$ matrix?  Then we would not have a square matrix for $x \in X$. I am considering that $f$ is still defined in the whole $U$ not only in $X$. Is this a valid argument? I do not see why the matrix would be square only in $X$ but not in a point in $U \setminus X$

Comment: You are confusing linear maps and matrices. When you ask if $df_x$ is the identity map, you should specify the domain and the codomain of the differential, just as you do for the map $f$ itself. The answer will depend on this.

Answer (score -1):

Let $v\in T_{x}U$ and take a curve $c: I \longrightarrow U$ such that $c(0) = x$ and $\dot{c}(0) = v \in T_{x} U \subset T_{x}X$. Like $c(t) \in U$ then $(f \circ c)(t) = c(t)$ and from here
\begin{equation}
df_{x}(v) = df_{x}(\dot{c}(0)) = \left. \frac{d}{dt}(\ f \circ c\ )(t) \right|_{t=0} =  \left. \frac{d}{dt}(\ c(t)\ ) \right|_{t=0} = \dot{c}(0) = v
\end{equation}
Therefore $df_{x}$ is the identity linear transformation.

Comment: Reread the hypotheses. Perhaps you need to take $c\colon I\to X$?

Comment: sorry i didn't read the question well